# Problem on continuous monotone function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function such that $f(f(x))=x, \forall x\in \mathbb R$. Then which of the followings are true?

1. $f$ is monotone
2. $f$ has to be identity
3. $f$ need not be monotone
4. $f(x)= x^{1/2}$

I think (4) and (2) are false, if we take $f(x)=-x$,but i am confused with the sentence 'need not be monotone',what does it  mean ?Which one is the answer? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Need not be monotone" means "is not necessarily monotone." (By the way, note that for 4., $f$ is not even defined on $\mathbb{R}_-$.)

Comment: f may or may not be monotone. is it?

Comment: Put differently: either 1. is true and 3. is false, or 3. is true and 1. is false.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to think of it is that we are saying $f$ is its own inverse everywhere, and in particular has a global inverse.  You are right about parts $(2)$ and $(4)$.  For the other two parts note that for a function to have an inverse it must be bijective, and in particular injective, in this case on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore because $f$ if continuous, it must be monotone on $\mathbb{R}$.